# How to retrieve JRI results as same as R terminal

Tags: java, r, output, jri

When I try the following in R terminal

```
library(MASS)
school.fre = painters$School
school.fre = table(school)
cbind(school.fre)
```

I get the following as the result

```
> cbind(school.fre)
  school.fre
A         10
B          6
C          6
D         10
E          7
F          4
G          7
H          4
```

But when I try this in a JRI application

```
Rengine re = new Rengine(args, false, new MyTextConsole());
REXP x;
        re.eval("library(MASS)");
        re.eval("school = painters$School");
        re.eval("school.freq = table(school)");
        x = re.eval("school.freq");
        System.out.println("school.freq::"+x);

        x = re.eval("cbind(school.freq)");
        System.out.println("\n\ncbind(school.freq)::"+x);
```

This is what I get

```
school.freq::[INT* (10, 6, 6, 10, 7, 4, 7, 4)]

cbind(school.freq)::[INT* (10, 6, 6, 10, 7, 4, 7, 4)].
```

How am I supposed to retrieve the first column(A,B,C..) of the result?

Also the barplot generated by the statement `re.eval("barplot(school.freq)");`  disappears so quickly.

I highly appreciate any guidance and links of tutorials in this regard as I am new to JRI.